# Mysql select with IN, limit rows to 1 for each match

Tags: mysql

lets say I have this table:

```
| id | record_id | date_updated |
|----|-----------|--------------|
| 1  | 1         | 19-03-2015   |
| 2  | 1         | 18-03-2015   |
| 3  | 1         | 17-03-2014   |
| 4  | 2         | 01-01-2015   |
| 5  | 2         | 05-02-2015   |
```

so the results I am looking for are :

```
| id | record_id | date_updated |
|----|-----------|--------------|
| 1  | 1         | 19-03-2015   |
| 4  | 2         | 01-01-2015   |
```

I have array with record ids.

$records = [1,2];

So I can do something like:

```
select * from `mytable` 
WHERE `record_id` IN ($records) 
AND mytable.date_update > 01-01-2014 
AND mytable.date_updated < 12-12-2015
```

so mysql will select records wich match date_updated criteria ( and record id ofc ), which are more then 1 for each record ID, basically I want to make him limit the rows for each $record_id to 1

If it is even possible.

//it is super hard to explain the problem, the real case is that this is a sub query of another query, but the real example is 10 rows query and 100 columns table, so it will be even more hard to explain the situation and for someone to read it / udnerstands it. Hopefully someone will understand my problem, if not I will try to explain more.

Thanks

Comment: Try to explain, what doesn't work with your query. Do you get the wrong output? If yes, which output?

Comment: i posted a edit at the bottom

Comment: not sure that solves your problem but there is a function called limit in mysql .[http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp]

Comment: Thanks, but I need limit for each and every record_id ( if u understand what I mean )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `group by` clause

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `mytable`
 WHERE id IN (
               SELECT min(id) 
                 FROM `mytable`
                 WHERE `record_id` IN ($records) 
                 AND mytable.date_update > 01-01-2014 
                 AND mytable.date_updated < 12-12-2015 
                 group by record_id
             );
```

Comment: superb, thank you very much. Because in my company we are running 5.1 ( mysql ) query gets stuck with sending data and has to be manually killed, but tested on my server with 5.6.23 works swell.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get the record per group, and since you need only once you can easily do as below

```
select t1.* from table_name t1 
where (
  select count(*) from table_name t2 
   where t1.record_id = t2.record_id
  ) > =0 
and 
t1.date_updated > '2014-01-01' and date_updated < '2015-12-12'  
group by t1.record_id ;
```

There are other way too using `left join`

```
select t1.* from table_name t1 
left join table_name t2 on t1.record_id = t2.record_id 
and t1.id >t2.id where t2.id is null
```

This will give you data with asc order with `id`

If you need data with max(id) for a `record_id` you can use

```
t1.id < t2.id
```

instead of

```
t1.id >t2.id
```

The same comparison you can do with first query.